# SQL CHARINDEX, SUBSTIRNG, PARSENAME better for Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, charindex

I have a table `[Evetns]`- rows of

```
EventName, EventDateTime
Sample, 25/12/2000
```

I have another table with period sets as `DateRange` type

```
period_range
1/1/1999,1/1/2001
1/1/1999,24/12,2000
```

So the result would be

```
Sample, 1
```

The event sample with event date 25/12/2000 is found in one range of the period data.

For this I have **created a function GetRange() as below**

```
 select  
    @var=count(*)
    --, convert(datetime,PARSENAME(REPLACE(period_range,',','.'),2),103),
    --convert(datetime,PARSENAME(REPLACE(period_range,',','.'),1),103)
from 
    [dbo].[DateRange]
where 
    @date between convert(datetime,PARSENAME(REPLACE(period_range,',','.'),2),103) 
            and convert(datetime,PARSENAME(REPLACE(period_range,',','.'),1),103)
```

the function receive the date from the **Events** table and pass it to above function which returns and int value and I am consuming the function as below,

```
select eventname,dbo.[getrange](eventdate) exist from [dbo].[Evetns]
```

The result set satisfies the requirement but need some suggestion for better performance. which should be use out of this?

- Which function will be good for performance CHARINDEX, SUBSTIRNG or PARSENAME?
- Is that good idea for bulk records?

any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: None of them will be better for performance. Your performance is going to stink because you are forced to use functions around your columns in the where predicates. This means an index scan, no way around that. The best thing you could for performance is to normalize your data and stop putting multiple values in a single tuple. This violates 1NF and causes all sort of problems. The other you have here is you are using a scalar function as a column value.This is another poor design from a performance standpoint.

Comment: yes that is violation of 1NF but the reason I can not change the db and want to gain this, what will be best way of that?

Comment: I already stated what would be the best way. When you are forced to use functions like this your performance is going to be horrible. I would consider removing the scalar function and converting it to an inline table valued function. But those where predicates are going to kill you. And of course you have date information obviously being stored as varchar. This means implicit conversion over and over. There are so many things wrong from a performance standpoint here. You can't fix the bad design with a good query. You need to fix the design.